# Difference between find and findOne

Tags: mongodb

when a variable say testVar is assigned with result of findOne, its availability is endless.
But a variable assigned with result of find() availability is only once.
Below is the command prompt dump

```
> var testVar = db.basic.findOne()
> testVar
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52abd2737164a542e93f1ebe"), "name" : "MongoDB" }
> testVar
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52abd2737164a542e93f1ebe"), "name" : "MongoDB" }
> testVar
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52abd2737164a542e93f1ebe"), "name" : "MongoDB" }


> var testVar = db.basic.find({"name":"MongoDB"})
> testVar
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52abd2737164a542e93f1ebe"), "name" : "MongoDB" }
> testVar
> testVar
>
```

Comment: more explanations is given here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`findOne` returns a single document, where `find` returns a cursor. Once you go through the cursor of `find`, you are at the end, and there are no more documents.